# XML Serialize Example, first steps

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have following exercise to do ...

I shall get following xml-file ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Mitarbeiterstatistik xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Mitarbeiter>
    <Vorname>Horst</Vorname>
    <Nachname>Schneider</Nachname>
    <Id>1</Id>
  </Mitarbeiter>
  <Mitarbeiter>
    <Vorname>Tanja</Vorname>
    <Nachname>Lindner</Nachname>
    <Id>2</Id>
  </Mitarbeiter>
</Mitarbeiterstatistik>
```

Now I tried following steps ...

I made a class Mitarbeiter!

```
public class Mitarbeiter
{
private string vorname;
private string nachname;
private int id;

public Mitarbeiter()
{

}

public Mitarbeiter(string vorname, string nachname, int id)
{
  this.vorname = vorname;
  this.nachname = nachname;
  this.id = id;
}

public string Vorname
{
  get { return vorname; }
  set { vorname = value; }
}

public string Nachname
{
  get { return nachname; }
  set { nachname = value; }
}

public int Id
{
  get { return id; }
  set { id = value; }
}
}
```

Then I made a class Mitarbeiterstatistik with a list for Mitarbeiter objects ...

```
[XmlRoot("Mitarbeiterstatistik")]
public class Mitarbeiterstatistik
{
  private List<Mitarbeiter> list = new List<Mitarbeiter>();

  [XmlArray("List")]
  public List<Mitarbeiter> List
  {
    get { return list; }
    set { list = value; }
  }
}
```

My Main-Class looks like ...

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Mitarbeiterstatistik maStatistik = new Mitarbeiterstatistik();
    Mitarbeiter ma1 = new Mitarbeiter("Horst", "Schneider", 1);
    Mitarbeiter ma2 = new Mitarbeiter("Tanja", "Lindner", 2);
    maStatistik.List.Add(ma1);
    maStatistik.List.Add(ma2);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Mitarbeiterstatistik));
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"D:\test.xml");
    serializer.Serialize(writer, maStatistik);
    writer.Close();
  }
}
```

Now I got following result ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Mitarbeiterstatistik xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  **<List>**
    <Mitarbeiter>
      <Vorname>Horst</Vorname>
      <Nachname>Schneider</Nachname>
      <Id>1</Id>
    </Mitarbeiter>
    <Mitarbeiter>
      <Vorname>Tanja</Vorname>
      <Nachname>Schneider</Nachname>
      <Id>2</Id>
    </Mitarbeiter>
  **</List>**
</Mitarbeiterstatistik>
```

No I have an Element "List" in my Xml-file ... :-)

What can I do against my problem ...

Is there only the possibility to define only a Mitarbeiter class and NO Mitarbeiterstatistik-Class?

Maybe as following?

```
  List<Mitarbeiter> list = new List<Mitarbeiter>();

  Mitarbeiter ma1 = new Mitarbeiter("Horst", "Schneider", 1);
  Mitarbeiter ma2 = new Mitarbeiter("Tanja", "Lindner", 2);

  list.Add(ma1);
  list.Add(ma2);

  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Mitarbeiter>), new XmlRootAttribute("Mitarbeiterstatistik"));

  XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"D:\test.xml");

  serializer.Serialize(writer, list);

  writer.Close();
```

**Or is there a chance to keep my Mitarbeiterstatistik-Class??? And disable my List-Element???**

Comment: Have you tried replacing `[XmlArray("List")]` with `[XmlArray()]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try Linq To Xml:

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Mitarbeiterstatistik"));

foreach (var mitarbeiter in list)
{
    xDoc.Root.Add(
            new XElement("Mitarbeiter",
                new XElement("Vorname" ,mitarbeiter.Vorname ),
                new XElement("Nachname" ,mitarbeiter.Nachname ),
                new XElement("Id" ,mitarbeiter.Id )));

}

xDoc.Save(@"d:\test.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get out of attribute "List" (as i undestand your question correctly) using [XmlElement] with name of element you want to get instead of [XmlArray]:

```
[XmlRoot("Mitarbeiterstatistik")]
public class Mitarbeiterstatistik
{
  private List<Mitarbeiter> list = new List<Mitarbeiter>();

  [XmlElement("Mitarbeiter")]
  public List<Mitarbeiter> List {get; set;}     
}
```